# objectForKey not working for pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

In the docs https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#relations-using-pointers
it says that in the example provided you can find the User who created the game

```
// say we have a Game object
PFObject *game = ...

// getting the user who created the Game
PFUser *createdBy = [game objectForKey:@"createdBy"];
```

But when I use the exact syntax since I want to populate the pointer in my "user" column

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
NSString *username = user.username;



// Inside my queryForTable method so PFObject is returned in 
 // tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object 

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fromUser = %@", user];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activities" predicate:predicate];

// Inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object 

PFUser *createdBy = [object objectForKey:@"user"];

NSLog(@"User to user ---%@", createdBy);
```

But All I get back is

```
User to user ---<PFUser: 0x7ff9024da860, objectId: aOisP569e3, localId: (null)> {
  // Nothing here
}
```

If I'm understanding correctly, am I also supposed to get back username, email etc in my user object?

**---UPDATE 1---**

looking at the Anypic app provided by parse it should return something like this

```
<PFUser: 0x7f7ff9fafc00, objectId: LfADtx1K2J, localId: (null)> {

// Stuff appears here
    displayName = "poopiu";
    facebookId = 130941340571204;
    profilePictureMedium = "<PFFile: 0x7f7ff9faf500>";
    profilePictureSmall = "<PFFile: 0x7f7ff9faf7f0>";
    username = I34MBM3WYSB5tjWIIvUvhH5fq;
}
```

but mine is empty even though I have a column called username that isn't undefined so I should get that inside my PFUser object

**--UPDATE 2--**

Here's what I get back from logging object like so...

```
NSLog(@"Object---%@", object);

<Activities: 0x7fbbebf42d20, objectId: rDwYI5Inuk, localId: (null)> {
user = "<PFUser: 0x7fbbee1367e0, objectId: SFL0kVZ17x>";
status = 0;
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following method call after you instantiated your `query`.

```
[query includeKey: "user"];
```

By default, queries do not grab information past the immediate object that was queried.

Comment: worked!  thanks, it was included in the Anypic source code but I totally missed that line of code <3

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `user` isn't `nil`? According to the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFUser.html#//api/name/currentUser) you must be logged in for `currentUser` to return a user object.

Comment: yeah, I'm sure because I also logged the object in [object objectForKey] and I don't get nil back but a pointer assigned to user so I do get results back from the query

Answer (score 0):

```
[createdBy fetch];

NSLog(@"User to user ---%@", createdBy);
```

Try this hope this will help